# How can you unpack method arguments to assign them class attributes?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I do this type of thing a lot:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        some_setup_stuff()
    def configure(
        self,
        color               = "#ffffff",
        weight              = 1,
        empathy             = 97,
        angle_x             = 0,
        angle_y             = 0,
        angle_z             = 0,
        displacement_x      = 0,
        displacement_y      = 0,
        displacement_z      = 0
        ):
        self.color          = color
        self.weight         = weight
        self.empathy        = empathy
        self.angle_x        = angle_x
        self.angle_y        = angle_y
        self.angle_z        = angle_z
        self.displacement_x = displacement_x
        self.displacement_y = displacement_y
        self.displacement_z = displacement_z
    def open(self):
        reveal_head()
```

Is there some neat, small, fairly sensible way to "unpack" the arguments passed to a class method into attributes of the class (while keeping the default values specified explicitly)? Like, I'm thinking maybe `locals()` could be used somehow around the first line in the method but it's not obvious to me.

So we could end up with something a bit like this:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        some_setup_stuff()
    def configure(
        self,
        color               = "#ffffff",
        weight              = 1,
        empathy             = 97,
        angle_x             = 0,
        angle_y             = 0,
        angle_z             = 0,
        displacement_x      = 0,
        displacement_y      = 0,
        displacement_z      = 0
        ):
        # magic possibly involving locals()
    def open(self):
        reveal_head()
```

And it could be used like this:

```
>>> box = Box()
>>> box.configure(empathy = 98)
>>> box.weight
1
>>> box.empathy
98
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html ?

Comment: Just use your approach. Explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky method. Build a `defaults` dictionary containing the default values for your allowed parameters. Then update `self.__dict__` with `**kwargs`, after some error checking on the keys:

```
class Box:
    def __init(self):
        pass
    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "weight": 1,
            "empathy": 97,
            "angle_x": 0,
            "angle_y": 0,
            "angle_z": 0,
            "displacement_x": 0,
            "displacement_y": 0,
            "displacement_z": 0
        }
        bad_args = [k for k in kwargs if k not in defaults]
        if bad_args:
            raise TypeError("configure() got unexpected keyword arguments %s"%bad_args)
        self.__dict__.update(defaults)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Now you can do:

```
box = Box()
box.configure(empathy = 98)
print(box.weight)
#1
print(box.empathy)
#98
```

But if you did:

```
box.configure(wieght = 2)
#TypeError: configure() got unexpected keyword arguments ['wieght']
```

Comment: I disagree and think it's a perfectly fine way of doing things. It's also fairly trivial to validate the `kwargs` passed it that's a concern.

Comment: Ah, yes...now that's more like it. Note that one could more succinctly check for bad args using the `any()` (or perhaps the `all()`) function.

Comment: @martineau I thought of that originally, but I wanted to also print the offending arguments. I suppose one could just loop through and raise an error on the first bad argument as well.

Comment: @pault Aaaah, nicely done! And with the error-checking there I'm feeling pretty ok with using this. Thanks muchly for your thoughts on this!