# Passing **kwargs to a function with args. Best practices?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Suppose I have a function that takes a lot of positional arguments like:

```
def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
  ...
```

It can be nice to call it by passing in a deconstructed dictionary like this:

```
args = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
foo(**args)
```

Is there anything to watch out for when calling an argument like this?

The first thing that comes to mind is that it will break if the functions argument names change, but that doesn't seem worse then accepting `**kwargs` in the function and accessing them with `kwargs['a']`, `kwargs['b']`, ect.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but this reminded me of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429772/how-can-you-unpack-method-arguments-to-assign-them-class-attributes).

Comment: your args are kwargs, and why don't you pass it a dictionary directly?

Comment: You might also note that you can pass it as a tuple representing args and not kwargs: `args = (1,2,3,4,5); foo(*args)`

Comment: No, nothing more to watch out for than that. (Unless the dictionary is a literal, in which case you should generally call it as `foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, …)`.)

Comment: first, the question is: does that `args` dict going to retain the order when passed to `foo()`? can it be relied on to always work or is it just a current implementation

Comment: @cryptonome: It matches parameters by name. No order involved.

Comment: @Ry- ah yeah true, shit i read positional & my brain got crosswired